# Spring Security: issues 403 after authorization with single granted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Used Spring Boot 2 + Spring Security Starter.

Authorizes users, but for some reason gives an error 403.

I tried to configure in different ways, but it does not work.

After successful authorization (the `loadUserByUsername` method works fine) it shows 403 on all pages with the / admin prefix, and before authorization, switching to any page with this prefix leads to a redirect to / login

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = {GET, POST})
    public String adminMainPage() {
        return "redirect:/admin/article";
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/article")
public class ArticleController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "", method = {GET, POST})
  public ModelAndView indexAdminPage(...){
  ...
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .userDetailsService(this)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login",
                        "/login*", "/assets/**", "/lib/**", "/page.scripts/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successForwardUrl("/admin")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> adminGrantedAuthoritySet = new HashSet<>() {{
        add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
    }};

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserRepository userRepository ) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserEntity> optionalUser = userRepository.findByLogin(login);
        if (optionalUser.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User by login '" + login + "' not found");
        } else {
            UserEntity userEntity = optionalUser.get();
            return new User(login, userEntity.getPassword(), adminGrantedAuthoritySet);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security there is a distinction between a `role` and an `authority`.
A `role` is an `authority` that is prefixed with `"ROLE_"`. In this example the authority `"ROLE_ADMIN"` is the same as the role `"ADMIN"`.

You are setting your admin `authorities` to be a list of `new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")`, but you are restricting access to `.hasAnyRole("ADMIN")`.

You need to change one of those configurations.
If you use `.hasAnyRole("ADMIN")`, then you should change the admin `authorities` list to use `new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")`.
Otherwise, if you want your list to be `new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")`, then you should use `.hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I will advice that you separate UserDetailsService from the WebSecurityConfig.

Have a separate class for UserDetailsService like

```
@Service("customCustomerDetailsService")
public class CustomCustomerDetailsService implements UserDetailsService  {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customers;    




    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)  {

      return this.customers.findByEmail(email)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username: " + email + " not found"));



    }

}
```

Then your UserEntity should implement UserDetails class where you set the authorities.See the answer //userdetails

```
@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
    }


    @Override
    public String getUsername() {

        return this.getEmail();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Transient
    private List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("ROLE_USER");
    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
```

Then you need DAOauthentication manager which makes use of the UserDetailsService like this:

```
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());

        return authProvider;

    }
@Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        return new CustomCustomerDetailsService();

    }
```

I don't know think putting everything in the WebSecurityConfig is good practice and it will be complicated and prone to errors!