# Spring Boot Security @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity with @RolesAllowed

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I tried to implement the basic role-based restricted API for that I used the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)` with `@RolesAllowed("DEVELOPER")` annotation.

When I tried with `inMemoryAuthentication` its worked without any issue. then I write my own `UserDetailsService` with `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. When these changes are done when we try to access the `@RolesAllowed` annotated REST method it will throw `AccessDeniedException` when the user has the appropriate role as well.

Thanks in advance.

**My sample project Repo** : [link](https://github.com/logavdm/Spring-Security-MethodSecurity)

**Please find my `pom.xml`**

```
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Security Auth Config :**

```
 @Autowired
 private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {   http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable().httpBasic();
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);
        }
        
        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            return provider;
        }
        
            
        
     @Bean
     public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
         return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
     }
                
     @Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
     }
```

**Method Security Enablement:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
```

**My Rest Controllers :**

```
@GetMapping("/")    
    public ResponseEntity<?> getWelcomeMsg(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hello");
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/admin")   
    @RolesAllowed("ADMINISTRATOR")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getWelcomeMsgAdmin(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hello admin");
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/developer")   
    @RolesAllowed("DEVELOPER")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getWelcomeMsgDeveloper(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hello dev");
    }
```

**My UserService implementation:**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    
    
    Map<String,UserDetails> mapUsers=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    public UserServiceImpl() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        User user1=new User("user1", encoder.encode("2005"), "DEVELOPER");
        User user2=new User("user2",encoder.encode("2005"), "ADMINISTRATOR");
        mapUsers.put(user1.getUsername(), user1);
        mapUsers.put(user2.getUsername(), user2);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return mapUsers.get(username);
    }
```

Comment: When we use SecurityConfig class with @Profile("basicauth") its works without any issue any idea on this.

Comment: You are not distinguishing correctly between roles and authorities. Take a look at this answer to understand the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023358/spring-security-issues-403-after-authorization-with-single-granted/59066667#59066667

Comment: Thank you @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana above mentioned works for me. gives a better understanding now.